# JavaScript If statement how to use correctly(MVC, Kendo Chart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have 4 properties and i want to draw a pie chart with them.

My scenerio is like this: When Model.Count equals to 0, i don't want to draw chart. So i added a if statement like this:

```
 <script>
        function createChart() {


            if (@Model.Count!=0) 
            {
```

But i get an error like(There is no applicable variable or member a):

```
 CS0103: 'a' isn't in the content(i translate this part)

 Satır 1150:       

         data: [{
Satır 1151:                    category: "fa",
Satır 1152:                    value: @a,
Satır 1153:
Satır 1154:                }, {
```

So how can i solve this problem? Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

I have model properties like this.

```
  @{
      if (Model.Count!=0)
         { 
int a, b, c, d= 0;

a= Convert.ToInt32(Model[0].Prop1);
b= Convert.ToInt32(Model[0].Prop2);
c= Convert.ToInt32(Model[0].Prop3);
d= Convert.ToInt32(Model[0].Prop4);

         }
     }
```

Here is my Kendo Chart Script.

```
<script>
    function createChart() {


        if (@Model.Count!=0) 
        {

        $("#chart55").kendoChart({
            theme: 'metro',
            title: {
                position: "bottom",
                text: "Maliyeti"
            },
            legend: {
                visible: false
            },
            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent",
                    template: "#= category #: \n #= value#TL"
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: "pie",
                startAngle: 150,
                data: [{
                    category: "fa",
                    value: @a,

                }, {
                    category: "za",
                    value: @b,

                }, {
                    category: "ka",
                    value: @c,

                }, {
                    category: "da",
                    value: @d,

                }

                ]
            }],

            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}"
            }
        });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(createChart);
    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (@Model.Count != 0)
```

Use

```
if ('@Model.Count' != 0)  //use single quotes as shown here
```

and make `int a, b, c, d= 0;` global ,intialize them outside `if statement`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like this while using the model value inside of javascript

you have to use single cotion like '@Model.Count'  where i used in below in Jquery.

```
<script>
function createChart() {


    if ('@Model.Count' !=0) 
    {
       // Your code
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: (There is no applicable variable or member a) i get this error.